# java drop and drag label to join correct image

Tags: java

this code is only allowing me to reject a string the second time to try to drop in a textArea where there is all ready a string.

```
public GridLayoutTest() {


JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout test");


 connection = getConnection();
try {  
    statement = (PreparedStatement) connection
     result = statement.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
    byte[] image = null;
    image = result.getBytes("image");
                JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                cellPanel.add(cellLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                cellPanel.add(droplabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                gridPanel.add(cellPanel);

    }

   }
    catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}

 }
```

Comment: If you are going to down-vote a new user, please have the courtesy to explain why it is being down-voted.

Comment: @leigero I can't agree with you more. Scaring off new users is awful and unnecessary.

Comment: @zahid Can you explain what results you are getting right now?

Comment: Time limit information removed from the question. Your question is  important yes, but it is no more important than any other question on this site. If you truly need help in a hurry, then your best bet is to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (see the link please), and to put in the effort to format your code well before posting it.

Comment: the code is working but the drag and drop does not work. it does drop anything and its certainty not accept or reject  the strings.

Comment: who is down voting who?

Comment: Again, please read the link. Your code formatting is sloppy -- again if you truly need us to put in effort to help you in a hurry, why make it harder for us to understand your code? Put in a little effort to format it please. Also your code does not work for *us* as we have no images that you have. Also your string1 and string2 variables are not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

So, two things, first...

```
public void DropTargetTextArea(String string1, String string2) {
```

Isn't a constructor, it's a method, note the `void`.  This means that it is never getting called.  It's also the reason why `DropTargetTextArea textArea = new DropTargetTextArea();` works, when you think it shouldn't.

Second, you're not maintaining a reference to the values you pass in to the (want to be) constructor, so you have no means to references them later...

You could try using something like...

```
private String[] values;

public DropTargetTextArea(String string1, String string2) {

    values = new String[]{string1, string2};
    DropTarget dropTarget = new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this, true);

}
```

And then use something like...

```
if (values[0].equals(dragContents) || values[1].equals(dragContents)) {
```

In the `drop` method.

In your `dragEnter`, `dragOver` and `dropActionChanged` methods you have the oppurtunity to accept or reject the drag action using something like `dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);` or `dtde.rejectDrag();`

**Updated with test code**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DragAndDropExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImageIcon ii1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\home.jpg");
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\images (2).jpg");
// Create a frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(ii);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(ii1);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4, 10, 10));

        JLabel testLabel = new DraggableLabel("test");
        JLabel testingLabel = new DraggableLabel("testing");
        panel.add(testLabel);

        panel.add(testingLabel);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(label1);

        Component textArea = new DropTargetTextArea("test", "testing");

        frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static class DraggableLabel extends JLabel implements DragGestureListener, DragSourceListener {

        DragSource dragSource1;

        public DraggableLabel(String text) {

            setText(text);

            dragSource1 = new DragSource();

            dragSource1.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this);

        }

        public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent evt) {

            Transferable transferable = new StringSelection(getText());

            dragSource1.startDrag(evt, DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop, transferable, this);
        }

        public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Drag enter");
        }

        public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Drag over");
        }

        public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Drag exit");
        }

        public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Drag action changed");
        }

        public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Drag action End");
        }

    }

    public static class DropTargetTextArea extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener {

        private String[] values;

        public DropTargetTextArea(String string1, String string2) {

            values = new String[]{string1, string2};

            DropTarget dropTarget = new DropTarget(this, this);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent evt) {
            if (!getText().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Reject drag enter");
                evt.rejectDrag();
            } else {
                evt.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
        }

        public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent evt) {
            if (!getText().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Reject drag over");
                evt.rejectDrag();
            } else {
                evt.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
        }

        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Drop exit");
        }

        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent evt) {
            if (!getText().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Reject dropActionChanged");
                evt.rejectDrag();
            } else {
                evt.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
        }

        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent evt) {

            if (!getText().isEmpty()) {

                evt.rejectDrop();

            } else {

                try {

                    Transferable transferable = evt.getTransferable();

                    if (transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                        String dragContents = (String) transferable.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                        evt.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);

                        if (values[0].equals(dragContents) || (values[1]).equals(dragContents)) {
                            System.out.println("Accept Drop");
                            setText(getText() + " " + dragContents);
                            evt.getDropTargetContext().dropComplete(true);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Reject Drop");
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    evt.rejectDrop();
                    evt.dropComplete(false);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have implemented what you have suggested. i am getting this error.. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
 at javaapplication24.DragAndDropExample.main(DragAndDropExample.java:66)
Java Result: 1

Comment: It sounds like you need to clean and build your project

Comment: Component textArea = new DropTargetTextArea();
this line of code is giving me an error which is under the   public static void main(String[] args) {

Comment: i removed the word static from this line of code 
  public class DropTargetTextArea extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener {

Comment: The constructor (you wrote), expects two `String` parameters, which are those values that it will accept if the text from the drop context matches...

Comment: do i need the "STATIC" in the public class DropTargetTextArea extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener??

Comment: Only if the class is a inner class (declared within) of your outter classes.  If it's a self contained class (within its own file), then no...

Comment: Then I would say, probably, given your errors, but I don't have you code so I'm only guessing...

Comment: Component textArea = new DropTargetTextArea(); this line of code is giving me an error which is under the public static void main(String[] args) { how do i fix this? shall i post the whole code above?

Comment: In what context?  From the `main` method? From the `DropTargetTextArea` class?

Comment: non-static variable values cannot be referenced from a static context                        values = new String[]{string1, string2};
This line give the above error from DropTargetTextArea class

Comment: Sounds like you've made `DropTargetTextArea` a static method instead of constructor, which is your original problem.  Remove the `static void` proceeding (what is now your method), it should read `public DropTargetTextArea(String string1, String string2) {`.  If you're having static issues, make the class static, not the method

Comment: i did that but still had errors. here is the DropTargetTextArea code 
   public static class DropTargetTextArea extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener {
               DragSource dragSource1;

public DropTargetTextArea(String string1, String string2) {

                       values = new String[]{string1, string2};
                       
 DropTarget dropTarget = new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this, true);

    


        }

Comment: i have removed the static from DropTargetTextArea code public static class DropTargetTextArea extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener  but now i have a new error

Comment: the new error is but now i have a new error on the line      Component droplabel = new DropTargetTextArea();.. the error says
                constructor DropTargetTextArea in class GridLayoutTest.DropTargetTextArea cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: are you able to tell me what this means error on the line Component droplabel = new DropTargetTextArea();.. the error says constructor DropTargetTextArea in class GridLayoutTest.DropTargetTextArea cannot be applied to given types; required: String,String found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: The `DropTargetTextArea` constructor requires two `String` values...there is no default constructor

Comment: Component droplabel = new DropTargetTextArea("test", "testing");
I HAVE ADDED THESE.. but when i run the program i cannot see the textArea of where the drop labels are susposed to go are not visible

Comment: It is, it's just blank as it doesn't contain anything.  Resize the window a bit, drag the one of the text labels to center of the window and drop it in.  `DropTargetTextArea` extends from `JLabel`, there fore it's transparent...

Comment: unless i stretch it out manually it doest set the frame size. here is the code for this.  frame.setSize(900,900);
  frame.setVisible(true);  
  frame.setResizable(true);
  frame.setLocation(550, 200);
    frame.pack();

Comment: Or override the `getPreferredSize` method in `DropTargetTextArea` to return a non-zero value, like `new Dimension(200, 200)` for example...

Comment: also how come the method does not work, it accepts both strings and doesnt reject any

Comment: I updated the examaple to use `getPreferredSize` - I only had your code to "guess" by.  If the logic isn't work for you, change it...

Comment: how can i reject a drop if its has all ready been assigned to another image or do i need assign the label to each one or something. it does not make sense to me at the moment

Comment: You can reject it in the `dragEnter`, `dragOver` and `dropActionChanged` methods, if `getText` returns a non empty `String` using `DropTargetDragEvent#rejectDrag` or `DropTargetDropEvent#rejectDrag` in the `drop` method if the same condition meet

Comment: do u have a example or tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: to do the rejects, im a hurry cus i need to get this working and submit so im low on time and stressing cannot think atm :(

Comment: That's pretty contextual, but basically, `if (getText().isEmpty()) evt.rejectDrag(); else evt.acceptDrag()`...should work in the methods I've just listed, but with your `drop` method, you will want to check that the text is empty before you try and import the text from the drag operation...

Comment: ive been working on this for 2 weeks now and still stuck thats why im not depending on anyone.

Comment: I added rejection support into the example

Comment: Also, you could take a look [How to drag and drop with Java 2, Part 1](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076358/swing-gui-programming/how-to-drag-and-drop-with-java-2--part-1.html)

Comment: you know the strings test and testing they should only drop into one textArea and be rejected by the rest. the whole point of this program is to have 30 images and 30 strings. each image matches 1 string. the user selects a string and drags it to textArea but only one textArea will accept the string and the rest of the textAreas will reject the strings... is this possible to do? i had this working but i had the string inside the method although it worked the strings needed to be passed through the class

Comment: Yes, the updated example should be doing this.  It will only accept either `test` or `testing` but only if the text hasn't been set it...

Comment: what it does is, it allows both the test and testing in each textArea but doesn't allow you to drop them the second time, before you can drop the strings in the textArea more than once.

Comment: Again, I only had you code example to go by.  You could drop the requirement for the second `String` parameter so that the text area will only accept the `String` value it is given.  You will can still check for a empty `String` value while the drag operation is in operation, but it will come down to the `drop` to determine if the value is actually valid or not

Comment: Okay, i will have play around and see what i can do. i need to implement it to my other program which is the same except it gets the images from a database. thanks

Comment: i think the problem is because of the gridlayout and trying to get the textArea below each image it only has one textArea in the program which is under each image when it is loaded from the database so the logic is not working. please can you help me. what do i need to do?

Comment: If I understand `GridLayout` correctly, it adds horizontally, then vertically (fills columns, then rows)

Comment: yes it does do that.. the images and the textarea are in a grid

Comment: Okay, so what's it not doing that you need it to?

Comment: i need it to be able to only accept one string which we have done in the previous code... i am trying to implement this here but because there is only 1 textArea is which added automatically under each image it is accepting both test and testing strings in each textArea but doesn't allow you to drop them the second time.. so do i need to add seperate textArea for each image for the logic to work?

Comment: i need one textArea per image rather than one textArea for all the images. how i do that i dont understand

Comment: i need one textArea per image rather than one textArea for all the images. how i do that i dont understand.. i have added the database code.. i think i may to move the dropLabel from that section but i get errors evry time. i think because the code is in there it automatically adds the same one textarea  under each image

Comment: i need the droplabel cellPanel but of the connection code.. how do i do this?

Comment: Sorry, only just logged back in :P

Comment: 16 hours later.. hmm i started a new question related to this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181763/code-seperation-database-and-java